# JpaRepository how to write when variable first character is upper case

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The models all generated by hibernate POJO, how to search if first character is upper case? Default it will find for "pDesc", which is wrong.

```
public interface ProductDao extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    public List<Product> findByPDesc(String PDesc); 
    //How to write if first character is upper case?
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product", catalog="somedb")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    //Some other code (constructors, getters & setters)
    private String PDesc;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as below, if you want to change the column name use the annotation you must confirm to the standard for the POJO property name (i.e. it must be pDesc, not PDEsc) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product", catalog="somedb")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    //Some other code (constructors, getters & setters)
    @Column(name = "NEW_COLUMN")
    private String pDesc;
}
```

By default this will map to column P_DESC if you ommit the @Column

```
public List<Product> findByPDesc(String pDesc);
```

Is correct.

Comment: Cannot the other way around? Thanks.

Comment: @LeeTeongHoe see updated answer if you want to change your column name change it with the annotation.

Comment: sorry currently I have partial done webapp over 50 tables, many variables are start with upper letter, early is generated by Hibernate mapping files and POJOs from database, that why default like that. That why I searching solution it is can some how remain "PDesc" and use JpaRepository. Thanks.

Comment: Refactor your code in Intelij it will be a lot easier in the long run.  Good luck